# Redirect email into shared hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, redirect, amazon-ec2

I have a domain named abc.com which is redirected to AWS EC2 instance by a record. 
Now I want to use email for this domain from my different server which is actually a shared hosting. Is it possible to do this? If yes how can I do this?

NB: To redirect entire domain I always use custom nameserver option from my domain. ex. 
ns1.xyz.com
ns2.xyz.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `A` or `CNAME` DNS records to point a domain name to your EC2 instance. You use `MX` records to tell other mail servers where to send email for your domain. So yes, you can easily point your email to a different location since you will be using a completely different DNS record type.